# How to plot the parametric plot of two linear time dependent equation with two variables?

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, complex

I am trying to plot the parametric plot between P1 and Q1. For this, I am using the code written below. I don't know where I am doing wrong. I think there are imaginary terms creating problems but is there any way to resolve this so that I can get the plot.

```
E1 = 10;
E2 = 10;
E1 = 1;
E2 = 1;
E0 = 1;
del0 = 1;
ka = 0.1;
G0 = 1;
wm = 1;
ome = 1;
gma = 0.01;
g0 = 0.3;
A00 = E0/(ka + I*del0);
a00 = E0/(ka - I*del0);
A10 = E1/(ka + I*(del0 + ome));
A11 = E1/(ka + I*(del0 + ome));
q1 = wm*a00*A10/(wm^2 - ome^2 + I*gma*ome);
p1 = I*ome*q1/wm;
sol = NSolve[{Q1[t] - q1*Exp[I*ome*t]*G0 == 0, P1[t] - p1*Exp[I*ome*t]*G0 == 0, 
   A1[t] - A10*Exp[I*ome*t] - A11*Exp[I*ome*t]*G0 == 0}, {Q1, P1, A1}]
ParametricPlot[{Evaluate[Q1[t]], Evaluate[P1[t]]} /. sol, {t, 0, 50}]
```

Comment: You’re using `Evaluate` incorrectly. `ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{...} /. Sol],...]`

Comment: The solutions Q1,P1,A1 are complex. You can plot only real or imaginary part.

Comment: What's the purpose of the first four lines? Couldn't it be accomplished in just two?